# Split one XML file section to multiple html File with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XML codes

**.xml**

```
<head>heading ONE</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
<section>Lorem ips</section>    
<head>heading TWO</head>    
<head>heading THREE</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
<section>Lorem ips</section>    
<head>heading FOUR</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
```

How do I write an XSLT to break it to multiple files like below

**.html**

```
<head>heading ONE</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
```

**.html**

```
<head>heading TWO</head>
```

**.html**

```
<head>heading THREE</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
```

**.html**

```
<head>heading FOUR</head>
<section>Lorem ips</section>
```

Comment: This a text book problem of XSLT 2.0 grouping using `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="head"`, see the spec or examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you input XML like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <head>heading ONE</head>
    <section>Lorem ips</section>
    <section>Lorem ips</section>
    <head>heading TWO</head>
    <head>heading THREE</head>
    <section>Lorem ips</section>
    <section>Lorem ips</section>
    <head>heading FOUR</head>
    <section>Lorem ips</section>
</root>
```

Then XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="head">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat(name(),'_',position(),'.html')}" indent="yes">
                <root>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </root>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you get seperate files for each head as desire.